# Include function not working

Tags: php

I am having a unexpected problem with including a header file in php.No error is showing.

When i use Code1  it works fine but  when i changed it to Code2  its not including the css style.Also tried  but still not same.i used this many times but don't know why it not working now.

Code1:

```
include 'includes/top.php';
```

Code2:

```
include '../includes/top.php';
```

Also tried using `require_once()` still not works
Thanx

Comment: because `../` tells it to look in the parent directory and the file is not there?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: y downvoting this post?

Comment: Are you saying you changed the location of `top.php`, or just changed the `include` code?

Comment: top.php is in the same place.... and using  `include'../includes/top.php';`  it showing the navigation links which are in top.php  but not including css.

Comment: @user2619187 I see.. well I updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Using

include 'includes/top.php';

and

include '../includes/top.php';

within the same file are trying to include different files.. If these statements are in a php page at `/path/page.php`, the first line would try to include `/path/includes/top.php` and the second would look for `/includes/top.php` because `../` tells it to go to parent directory. Perhaps both of these files exist? The latter may not have the correct css or something.

Answer (score 0):

Just debug your code in any browser and check the source code and see how the Css file is been linked by the browser. If it is not including the CSS that shows that the path is not the right one. It will help to explain the structure of your website.